# Ruby Array Select - Nested Maps with Wildcard

Tags: arrays, json, ruby, amazon-web-services

I've got a JSON response and I'd like to extract values for a given key across multiple indexes.

```
json_object['resources'].select {|a| a["type"] == "aws_subnet" && a["name"] == "private"}.first["instances"]
```

This gets me an array of instances. Each instance contains an attributes map element, which then contains an ID element. All I'm trying to do is get an array of all the IDs. Doing the following:

```
json_object['resources'].select {|a| a["type"] == "aws_subnet" && a["name"] == "private"}.first["instances"][0..3]["attributes"]["id"]
```

Gets me the dreaded:

```
TypeError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)
```

Comment: can you a sample of `json_object`?

Comment: The error message is telling you that you are trying to use String as a integer, you can just add .to_i on that variable where error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at how you've structured the statement, the issue is with your range selection - `[0..3]`

The range selection will return an `array`, not a `hash`.

Trying to fetch `["attributes"]` from an `array` raises the TypeError because arrays are indexed by `Integer`s, not `String`s.

to fix this, I'd recommend using the `map` function to iterate over the instances, grabbing the id value of each:

```
json_object['resources'].select {|a| a["type"] == "aws_subnet" && a["name"] == "private"}.first["instances"][0..3].map { |inst| inst["attributes"]["id"] }
```

Also, if you'd like to optimize, I'd recommend using `find` instead of `select` followed by `first`. `find` looks for the first match, which accomplishes the same thing but with better performance.

With that, here's what you're looking for:

```
ids = json_object['resources'].find {|a| a["type"] == "aws_subnet" && a["name"] == "private"}["instances"][0..3].map { |inst| inst["attributes"]["id"] }
```

*Note: Per Thang's comment, it'd be helpful in the future to include an example of the JSON response you're trying to parse so we can make sure the answer works*

Comment: That's just what I was looking for. I had a feeling I needed to use a map, but couldn't get the syntax quite right.